# Display Matched and Non Matched Values based on a slicer value Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a Viewership table which tells which customer watches which asset.  Based on the asset filter, I need to display the customers who watched the show & customers who didn't watched the show. below is my example table

[image]

If the asset_id selected as 1 in the slicer, the desired output will be as below

[image]

I have tried creating a cross-join table with asset_id and customer_id , but that approach taking much time with large data.  Request the experts here to suggest the best optimal solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a new table "Asset":

[image]

This table contains unique assets, and we will use it to create a slicer that affects DAX measure but does not affect the visual (table). To achieve that, the Asset table must be disconnected from the Viewership table (no relationships).

In your viewership table, I just renamed "asset" to "asset_id", to be consistent:

[image]

Next, create a measure:

```
Status = 
  VAR Selected_Asset = SELECTEDVALUE(Asset[asset_id])
  VAR Customer_Asset = SELECTEDVALUE(Viewership[asset_id])
RETURN
IF(Customer_Asset = Selected_Asset, "Watched", "Not Watched")
```

Result:

[image]

Slicer here is created from the "Asset" table, and table is a table visual with customer_id and asset_id from the Viewership table (set them as "don't summarize" values). I turned off "total", assuming you don't need it.

This design requires to set Asset slicer to "single selection" mode, to make sure that you are only getting one value from it. If you want the model to work with multi-select slicer, change DAX measure as follows:

```
Multi Status = 
  VAR Selected_Assets = ALLSELECTED(Asset[asset_id])
  VAR Customer_Asset = SELECTEDVALUE(Viewership[asset_id])
RETURN
IF(Customer_Asset IN Selected_Assets, "Watched", "Not Watched")
```

Result:

[image]

**Edit:**

To make it work at the customer level:

```
Customer Status = 
  VAR Selected_Assets = ALLSELECTED(Asset[asset_id])
  VAR Customer_Assets = VALUES(Viewership[asset_id])
  VAR Assets_Watched = COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(Customer_Assets, Selected_Assets))
RETURN
IF(Assets_Watched > 0, "Watched", "Not Watched")
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation: store selected assets in a table variable. Then, store assets visible per customer in another table variable. Find an intersect of the two tables (what they have in common), and count intersect rows. If none - not watched, otherwise watched. If you want, you can actually display the number of movies watched (just return "Assets_Watched" instead of IF statement).

Comment: thanks RADO. I tried and its works fine. may i ask you one for help. If a customer watches at least one asset, his status should come as "Watched" when see the data at  customer level. In this output, customer_id 1 has both "Watched" & "Not Watched", so at the customer Level his status will be "Watched". I tried to get this done by using MAX on the measure created..but its not worked

Comment: thanks much @RADO. its working. may i ask one more help. I have created one more slicer (copy of the asset table) which is for not watched assets. I have created same customer_status measure with second asset_id slicer and named it as customer_status_2 .  I have filtered out only "Watched" from customer_status & "Not Watched" from customer_status_2.  now when i select asset_id = 1  in first slicer and asset_id = 2 in second slicer , I will see customer_id 4  in the output ( Who has watched only asset _id 1) .

Comment: This is working when I select values from both slicers. If i select values only from first slicer the output table goes blank. please let me know if am clear

Comment: @bmsqldev - your last requirement is hard to understand. You can get better help if you post it as a new question, were you can clearly explain the desired results. I'll try to help once I better understand what you need.

Comment: Could you help to me achieve below.  I need the count of customers instead the list of customers. I tried some methods its not working. I will add a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249859/display-count-of-users-based-on-multiple-slicer-values-power-bi